# How to deserialize differently-named collections of the same object with @JacksonXmlProperty?

Tags: java, xml-deserialization, jackson-dataformat-xml

We are trying to convert deserialize an XML to JSON. For the most part, it is working fine. We've annotated our POJOs with @JacksonXmlProperty. But we have a new scenario that's causing problems. The problem is using 2 different collections of the same object, but with different names.

Here is a simplified XML input:

```
<Invoice>
    <Payments>
        <Payment>
            <Amount>
        </Payment>
    </Payments>
    <Refunds>
        <Refund>
            <Amount>
        </Refund>
    </Refunds>
</Invoice>
```

The corresponding POJO look like this:

```
public class Invoice {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "Payments")
    protected List<Payment> payments;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Refunds")
    protected List<Payment> refunds;
}
```

It deserializes without exception, but the properties of the refunds in the Refunds collection are all null.

Is there a way to do this without creating a Refund POJO?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually with the JacksonXML annotations, and not with using the same object in different collections. Refunds is also a collection, so it should have the @JacksonXMLElementWrapper as well, like so:

```
public class Invoice {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "Payments")
    protected List<Payment> payments;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "Refunds")
    protected List<Payment> refunds;
}
```

It works fine like this. Incidentally, it also works if you used a simple Refund class which simply extends Payment. In case you actually want a different class.

```
public class Refund extends Payment {
}
```